# RStudio Plotting stock graphs by date

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I've been trying to plot a graph including stock prices by date in Rstudio with the following code:

```
plot(diff.open ~ date, final2, type = "l", col = "red")

lines(final2$diff.hits)

lines(final2$`bitcoin*`*15, col = "blue")

legend(1, 400, legend=c("Difference in Open. Price", "Articles*15", "Difference in Google Hits"),
   col=c("red", "blue", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=08)
```

This produces the following graph:[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcj40.png)

The x-axis shows the dates how we want to, however I can't figure out how add any other lines to the code. We only get one line but we want three seperate ones showing for the variables:

- difference in open (stock value)
- articles (amount of articles)
- google hits (amount of relative google searches)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to format date variable.
Try something like this:

```
final2$date <- as.Date(final2$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```